# How to get Numbers from a String

Tags: javascript

Getting Numbers from a string and inserting them into array.
splitting the string would result into single character and thus does not solve my problem.

var str="(235+456+2+3-6-(2*5))"

```
Output Must be:
[235,456,2,3,6,2,5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression for it. It looks only for connected numbers.

```js
console.log('(235+456+2+3-6-(2*5))'.match(/\d+/g));
```

Comment: Superb!! Thanks It Worked.

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `String.match` function:

```
var str="(235+456+2+3-6-(2*5))"
    numbers = str.match(/\b\d+?\b/g);

console.log(numbers);  // ["235", "456", "2", "3", "6", "2", "5"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about number output:

`"(235+456+2+3-6-(2*5))".match(/\d+/g).map(e=>+e);`